# Error Cypress: Request failed with status code 500

Tags: cypress

CODE CYPRESS:

[image: cypress code]

ERROR CODE:

[image: error]

Why does this error appear? I don't understand.

Comment: Please avoid adding screenshots of your code snippet. Add the code directly to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle this you have catch exceptions that are caused by your application. Go to `cypress/support/index.js` and write:

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
})
```

This will catch your exceptions globally for all tests.

Comment: This should not be used in production tests.

Answer (score 0):

**Why does this error appear?**

Take a look at the last network call,

> PUT  500  /api/pacientes/**undefined**?usuario=**undefined**

There are two **undefined** in the call. This means some variables are not set correctly within the app, so the app is not providing a valid URL to the API.

Is it because the test needs to provide some configuration? Or perhaps the app is broken.

usuario === Username, so is the login not correct?